# Extracting nth value from an imported text file

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I'm importing 100 of a specific file, whose format isn't supported by Mathematica. The file imports as a text file fine though by the below commands:

```
SetDirectory["MyFilepath here"];
MyFilenames = FileNames["*.fileextension"]
MyListofData = Import[#, {"Data"}] & /@ MyFilenames
```

The data imports like the following:

```
{{Some text here, more text, Word = 4590, More words},{Some text here, more text, Word = 381, More words},{Some text here, more text, Word = 2406, More words}...etc}
```

I need to extract the numbers follow "`Word =` ". I.e. to get `{{4590},{381},{2406}}`

I've tried a few different options listed by previous questions, but I'm stumped. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: How you can deal with this will depend on the details. Look at the FullForm. Is it: {"Some text here, more text, Word = 4590, More words"} or is it: {"Some text here", "more text", "Word = 4590", "More words"} Or is it importing in some other way?

Comment: It's importing like {{Some text here, more text, Word = 4590, More words},{Some text here, more text, Word = 381, More words}}, with no " " at all.

Comment: `Flatten[StringCases[#, DigitCharacter ..] & /@ text]`

Comment: @Alan this worked thanks! There are multiple numbers in the list and I want the 2nd value from each data set, is that possible?

Comment: If you can successfully import data, then include a representative sample of this data to get focused answers. Thanks.

Comment: `(Part[#, 2] &) /@ 
 Catenate /@ (StringCases[#, DigitCharacter ..] &) /@ nestedtextlists`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that data consists of a list of lists of strings Like e.g.:

```
 dat = {{"Some text here", "more text", "Word=4590", 
    "More words"}, {"Some text here", "more text", "Word=381", 
    "More words"}, {"Some text here", "more text", "Word=2406", 
    "More words"}};
```

Then you may extract the number after "Word=" and change it into an integer by e.g.:

```
StringCases[#, 
    RegularExpression["Word=(\\d+)"] :> ToExpression["$1"]] & /@ 
  dat // Flatten

{4590, 381, 2406}
```

The "RegularExpression[..]" extracts the number as a string and ToExpression[..] changes it into an integer.

Comment: Unfortunately the data doesn't come out as strings so this wouldn't work, thanks though!